# p-channel and n-channel MOSFET small signal models

Tags: mosfet

What is the difference between the p-channel and n-channel MOSFET small signal models? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference in a given *model* is that signs for voltages and currents are changed as appropriate.

There are differences in the *actual devices* that stem from physics: holes are not as mobile as electrons.  That is reflected by the performance that you can achieve in a given FET, and in the *numbers* that you plug *into* a given model.

Comment: Ok thank you, may textbook only brushes over it with a n-channel mosfet.

Comment: Textbooks like npn BJT transistors and n-channel FETs because source is positive.

Comment: P-channel FETs and PNP transistors will almost always have intrinsically lower performance than their brethren, because of the whole hole mobility thing.